# Interpolation format error at MYSQL_PASSWORD in "db" service of docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

As I try to start my containers with `docker-compose up` I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "db": "MYSQL_PASSWORD=..."
```

The provided password contains special characters(!, $, @, &, #). I believe that these ones are causing the problem.

Is there any way to provide the password like this in the `docker-compose.yml`? How can I pass it to the service in a valid format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `$` character in your `MYSQL_PASSWORD` environment variable. You should escape it by adding `$` in front of the `$` character : `$$`. For example, if your password is `!$@&#`, you should write :

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=!$$@&#
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and secure way is to use docker secret with your password. Then put in compose 
 MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/your_secret_name